# Loop each hour to the same hour tomorrow

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to get each hours from the current hour and 24 hours ahead (21:00 tonight to 21:00 tomorrow). The loop below just loops to 24.

```
var i;
var date = new Date;
var hours = date.getHours();

for(i = hours; i <= 24; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

What should I do to accomplish this?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/64XDf/

Comment: u want to print only?? surely you want to do someting else. question not clear.. do you want to print 1,2...24 twice?

Comment: @Sami I'm going to use this for loop to a chart function. user3678068 below has already answered with a correct solution :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use modular arithmetic

```
for(i = 0; i <= 24; i++) {
    console.log((i+hours)%24);
}
```

show 24 for hour 0:

```
for(i = 0; i <= 24; i++) {
    var h = (hours+i)%24;
    if (h == 0) h = 24;
    console.log(h);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I get rid of the zero that comes after 24 and before 1? Changing `0` to `1` in `for` didn't do the trick :/

Comment: @ErikEdgren, I'm afraid the easiest way is to check if it's 0. answer has been updated

Comment: Thank you once more. I'll accept your answer when I can :)

Comment: Good solution...others do work as well FYI, some of us have to revert to measly if/else statements and ternary operators instead of that fancy modular arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you're looking for?

```
var i;
var date = new Date;
var hours = date.getHours();

for(i = hours; i <= hours+24; i++) {
    if(i<25){
        console.log(i);
    }else{
        console.log(i-24);
    }
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XKZ6r/)

Answer (score 1):

Your end condition is off by `hours`, and you need to adjust for the 24 hours limit. One solution is to do this,

```
var date = new Date;
var hours = date.getHours();

for (var i = hours; i <= hours+24; i++) {
  console.log((i > 23) ? i - 24 : i);
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ElliottFrisch/64XDf/3/)